# Assets not recognising image manipulations after upgrade to 2.0.5

Tags: assets

I have just updated a site to Assets 2.0.5. When I update the indexes, I get a list of files with the heading "There are some entries in the database that are out of date"

What does that mean and how safe is it to delete these files?

Coincidentally, after the update, I can no longer get EE image manipulations - I just get blanks where the images are supposed to be - no error messages.

My template code is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="catalogue" status="open|closed"}  

  {product}  

 <a href="{path='catalogue/products/{entry_id}'}">  

 <img src="{images:catalogue}" alt="{title}" title="&copy;&nbsp;Design by MaJools" />  

 </a>{spiel}  

  {/product}  

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

{product} is a matrix field type

{images:catalogue}, where  images is the assets field type and catalogue is the EE manipulation.

If I just use {images} I get the image un-manipulated

This worked well before the upgrade.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you got template debugging turned on? FWIW, I've never actually used EE's native image manipulations; have always used image resizing plugins like CE Image in the templates.

Comment: @Tyssen - yes tried all that, no indications of what's going on that I could see. I gave up and went with CE Image - brilliant program.

Comment: Would still like an answer to the "Files are out of date" question - anyone? Why would assets think files are out of date?

Comment: Have you checked that the images are actually there on the filesystem? What filetypes are these images?

Comment: The images are actually there. Filetypes are png.

Comment: John, do these filenames have some specific characters such as umlauts, accented vowels or the like?

The message you're getting means that there are some files that are indexed but the corresponding file cannot be found on the server - wonky characters or illegal file types would cause that.

Comment: Andris - no wonky charcters or illegal file names.

Answer (score 1):

If the images are there and the filetype is that of a regular PNG then the chances are this is just Assets checking to be extra sure you want to still have those images recognised.

***Firstly, ensure that you have ALL images and the database backed-up*** just to be sure. Then hit the delete button. This is just to delete Assets' record of the file. Afterwards you should still have all of your images in place and the indexing should tell you it is complete. Your images should appear in your entries again.

**Note**: Just to point out that I'm not official support for Assets and anything involving hitting delete buttons is always risky which is why I say to have a solid backup in advance so you can recover if all else fails. I can't be held responsible for any loss of data as a result of following this advice.

Having said the above though I'm pretty sure that you'll find this solves the issue and the images themselves or associations will still be there. If you'd rather wait for one of the official support reps to hop on and check with them than that's fine. :)

Comment: Thank you for your insights. While what you say is reassuring, I would hope that P&T would look into why this is happening - either supply an explanation or maybe this is a bug? At least we need to know why Assets tells us to delete files when indeed it does not do so - seems very odd. And yes, I do have solid backups.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's not a bug but just Assets being a little on the cautious side. If it has a record of a file which has changed then it gets cautious and asks. You may want to delete the record and associated meta data or your may just have renamed it or it has altered in some way and you want to keep record associations. It can't know for sure so Assets err's on the side of caution. So it's a feature rather than a bug. Once things have been re-indexed it will be fine.